# Velocity in frame $S$ and $S'$

Tags: special-relativity

If I take the Lorentz position transforms between two inertial frames, $S$ and $S'$ moving with relative velocity $u$ along a common axis (say $x-x'$), then:

$$x'=\gamma(x- ut)$$
$$y'=y$$
$$z'=z$$
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{ux}{c^2}\right)$$

If the particle has velocity $(v_x,v_y,v_z)$ in $S$ then in $S'$ we have (I think):
$$v_x'=\frac{v_x-u}{1-\frac{v_xu}{c^2}}$$
I was unsure for the $y-y'$ and $z-z'$ axis, I was wandering if we would obtain:
$$v_y'=\frac{v_y}{\gamma(1-\frac{v_xu}{c^2})}$$
And likewise for $v_z'$? The reason I am asking is I was wondering if the velocity in the $x-x'$ axis could effect the time dialation in the $y-y'$ axis and hence $v_y'$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see this just take the points $(t = 0, y = 0)$ and $(t = T, y = v_yT)$ in $S$ and transform them into $S'$. The point $(0, 0)$ goes to $(0, 0)$ but the point $(T, v_yT)$ goes to $(\gamma T, v_yT)$. So the velocity in $S'$ is $v'_y = v_y/\gamma$ i.e. it is reduced.